# How to update wallpaper changes in windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

Using java code I edited the jpg image which is set as wallpaper. And Now I want windows to update the wallpaper so that changes could be seen.
I don't want to set wallpaper with code due to some technical issues.

My code so far :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
void broadcast{
    char filepath[225];
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETDESKWALLPAPER, sizeof (filepath) - 1, filepath, SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
}
```

But this code is not updating wallpaper. I am using JNI.

Comment: `SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER` sounds much more promising than `GET`. Have you tried that?

Comment: But it will set wallpaper. And I don't want to change wallpaper through coding. I edited Image and want windows to update it. @IgorTandetnik

Comment: I'd try setting it with that same file name.

Comment: Doing this changes the windows setting. Suppose user has selected more than 1 files as wallpaper. If I set it through code, it will set only 1 image. And there are other issues too. @IgorTandetnik

Comment: Moreover windows will not show wallpaper in usual way. It will directly set the jpg file as wallpaper if I code it to do so where on the other hand it usually read jpg files and create new one and then set it as wallpaper and update it after timeout @IgorTandetnik

Comment: Ok then, another thing to try is to broadcast `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message, with `SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER` in `wParam`

Comment: Not working. @IgorTandetnik The code I used is : `SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, 0, WM_SETTINGCHANGE);`.

Comment: May I humbly suggest you [read the fine manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725497.aspx): "To send the `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message to all top-level windows, use the `SendMessageTimeout` function with the `hwnd` parameter set to `HWND_BROADCAST`."

Comment: You'll need to be more clear as to what you wish to do. I read this as "I want to change the setting but I don't want to change the setting". And yes, reading the documentation is a pre-requisite.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't want to change settings. I just want to notify window to update its wallpaper. I mean if `abc.jpg` is set as wallpaper and I edited it with say photoshop and saved it. But the changes will not be seen until I log into window next time.

Comment: You achieve that by SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER

Comment: I don't have much experience in C language. Did the answer you are telling worked for you. I already tried that method as `SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, 0, SMTO_NORMAL, 1000, 0);`. But it also not worked. @IgorTandetnik